# WCF: How to stop service when host closed?

Tags: wcf, servicehost

I am trying to add my custom (not WCF) service to my WCF.
It is hosting in Windows Service and in IIS.

```
I added call
serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));
...
// ok, works.
```

When win service stopping it calls

```
if (serviceHost != null && serviceHost.State != CommunicationState.Closed) serviceHost.Close();
```

But my custom service still works.
The question is: how to stop my service when host is stopped?

Comment: I'm not sure, If windows service stopped then it impossible that your service will be active. Looks like the service is not stopping properly or `serviceHost.Close()` is not getting called.

Comment: The reason is: it is not wcf service, it is my custom service. In other words: what serviceHost calls to stop hosting service?